# Why are restrictions important?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

When simplifying expressions, why do we add on restrictions for the simplified form if the original form was undefined at a certain point? The simplified form *is* defined at those points, so why should it be restricted?

An example of what I mean:

$$\frac{x^2−1}{x−1}=x+1, x≠1$$

Comment: It's a condition on the equality (see [Leibniz's law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_of_indiscernibles)). When $A = B$ unconditionally, we can substitute $A$ for $B$ (and vice versa) unconditionally. When both $A$ and $B$ are expressions in variables $x, y,$ etc, there is an implied quantification $\forall x, y,$ etc. When either $A$ or $B$ is undefined for certain values for $x, y,$ etc, the equality does not hold unconditionally anymore.

Comment: @RossMillikan Thank You!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In short, it's because a function is all about the rule and domain of definition.

For example, let's consider the real-valued functions $f(x)=\frac{x^2}{x}$ and $g(x)=x$, with their maximal real domains of definition. In particular, then, $\mathrm{dom}(f)=\Bbb R\smallsetminus\{0\}$ and $\mathrm{dom}(g)=\Bbb R$. That means that $f$ and $g$ are **not** the same function, since their domains are not the same. Now, where *both* are defined, the rule is the same. However, this isn't enough for them to be the same function. Now, $f$ **is** a restriction of $g$ (specifically, to $\Bbb R\smallsetminus\{0\}$), so they are *certainly* related functions.

**Edit**: In the context of your previous question (regarding limits and restrictions), it is worth noting that $f$ can be *continuously extended* to $g$, since for any $\varepsilon>0$ there exists $\delta>0$ (in particular, in this case, $\delta=\varepsilon$) such that for any $0<|x|<\delta$ we have $\left|f(x)-0\right|<\varepsilon$.

Comment: Simple and concise. +1

Comment: @CameronBuie Thank You!